# How do you get MySQL to not treat non-ASCII as ASCII?

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (name varchar(32)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('adam');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('ádam');
```

The problem query:

```
SELECT name FROM test WHERE username='ádam';
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| adam     |
| ádam     |
+----------+
```

How do I get MySQL to search for user input *exactly* and not implicitly transliterate it to ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT name FROM test WHERE CONVERT(name USING BINARY) = 'ádam';

+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| ádam  |
+-------+
```

Comment: You can also add `AND name = 'ádam'` if you want to use an index.